# Getting error in ipfs.add() method wile using ipfs with ejs to upload file

Tags: node.js, ejs, ipfs, ipfs-http-client, ipfs-cli

I am trying to upload a file to ipfs using ejs app. I have go to a lot of posted problems but i have not seen a problem like i am getting.

when we use `ipfs.add()` method with a simple string `"Hello World"` it still worked for others but in my case it is throwing an error.

This is the code where I try to upload the file:

**upload file code (upload.ejs):**

```
<div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header">Upload Document to IPFS</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="/ipfs" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-10">
                            <input type="file" name="filetoupload" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">UPLOAD</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**app.js file:**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const fileupload = require('express-fileupload');
const { create } = require("ipfs-http-client");

const app = express();

app.use(fileupload());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(8010, () => {
  console.log("Application started and Listening on port 8010");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home");
});


const ipfs = create({host:'localhost',port:6001,protocol:'http'});
app.get("/ipfs/:hashcode", async function(req, res) {
    const hashcode = req.params.hashcode;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    let result = false;
    if (hashcode) {
        const stream = ipfs.cat(hashcode);
        let data = ''

        for await (const chunk of stream) {
        // chunks of data are returned as a Buffer, convert it back to a string
        data += chunk.toString()
        }
        result = true;
        res.json({
            'success': result,
            'data': data
        });

            
        
    } else {
        res.json({
            'success': result,
            'data': ''
        });
    }
  
});

app.post("/ipfs", (req, res) => {
    
    const file = req.files.filetoupload;
    const filename = req.files.filetoupload.name;

    console.log("here")
    const filepath = 'files/' + filename;

    file.mv(filepath, async(err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log("ERROR: Upload File Error!");
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        const hashcode = await addFile(filename,filepath);
        console.log("HHHHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASSSSSSSSSSSSHHHHHH...."+hashcode); // here i am gettin undefined
        fs.unlink(filepath, (err  => {
            if(err) console.log(err);
        }))
        res.render("upload",{filename, hashcode});
    })
    
    
});
// ipfs api: https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#ipfsadddata-options
const addFile = async(filename,filepath) => {

    try {
        const file = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
        console.log("------------------(Here Before await)--------------------\n");
        // const added = await ipfs.add(file);
        // const added = await ipfs.add({path: filename, content:file});
        const added = await ipfs.add("hello world"); // here i am getting error
        console.log("------------------(Here After await)--------------------\n"); // after error this lone is ignored
        // console.info(added);
        return added.cid.toString();
    } catch (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    
}
```

I am getting in addFile() method in app.js `const added = await ipfs.add("hello world");`

**Docker Compose file**

```
version: '3'
services:
  ipfs:
    image: ipfs/go-ipfs:latest
    container_name: ipfs_host
    volumes:
      - ./export:/export
      - ./ipfs_data:/data/ipfs
    ports:
      - '4001:4001'
      - '4001:4001/udp'
      - '127.0.0.1:8080:8080'
      - '127.0.0.1:7010:7010'
```

**Error Snap (Updated):**
The error snap is updated after some suggestion of @discordian
@discordian trace that i have no docker-compose, but after that i am still getting the error.

```
abidullah@abidullah:~/Desktop/BC Project/document-verification-dapp$ ./start.sh
Building images
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 410, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 70, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 153, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
[29229] Failed to execute script docker-compose
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 410, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 70, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 153, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
[29234] Failed to execute script docker-compose
install libraries
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘files’: File exists
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/abidullah/Desktop/BC Project/document-verification-dapp/client/node_modules/iso-random-stream
npm ERR! dest /home/abidullah/Desktop/BC Project/document-verification-dapp/client/node_modules/.iso-random-stream-CBO0cinM
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/abidullah/Desktop/BC Project/document-verification-dapp/client/node_modules/iso-random-stream' -> '/home/abidullah/Desktop/BC Project/document-verification-dapp/client/node_modules/.iso-random-stream-CBO0cinM'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/abidullah/.npm/_logs/2022-07-04T18_52_00_411Z-debug-0.log
start service
Application started and Listening on port 8010
```

Comment: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6001` <-- there's your problem. You specify for it to connect to a node listening on 6001, but there is no node listening on 6001. Could be related to your `docker-compose` errors, unsure.

Comment: here is my docker compose code:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ipfs:
    image: ipfs/go-ipfs:latest
    container_name: ipfs_host
    volumes:
      - ./export:/export
      - ./ipfs_data:/data/ipfs
    ports:
      - '4001:4001'
      - '4001:4001/udp'
      - '127.0.0.1:8080:8080'
      - '127.0.0.1:7010:7010'
```

Comment: One issue is `docker-compose` doesn't appear to be installed. See your errors `/start.sh: line 4: docker-compose: command not found`.

Comment: The other *potential* issue I see is the default API port is 5001, but you've specified 6001.

Comment: Thanks @discordian, after checking docker in my system i found that it is not installed in my system. Now i am working on that let see after installation.

Comment: @Discordian after your suggestion i am still getting errors, you can see the error snap in the above question section

Comment: Now it’s complaining a file is missing. Where did you find this setup? There seems to be issues with it